# Sorting the CSV file based on by descending order of lawyer salary

Tags: python

I must use Python to solve this. Given a file `salaries.csv` with this structure:

```
City,Job,Salary

Delhi,Doctors,500

Delhi,Lawyers,400

Delhi,Plumbers,100
London,Doctors,800
London,Lawyers,700
London,Plumbers,300
Tokyo,Doctors,900
Tokyo,Lawyers,800
Tokyo,Plumbers,400
Lawyers,Doctors,300
Lawyers,Lawyers,400
Lawyers,Plumbers,500
Hong Kong,Doctors,1800
Hong Kong,Lawyers,1100
Hong Kong,Plumbers,1000
Moscow,Doctors,300
Moscow,Lawyers,200
Moscow,Plumbers,100
Berlin,Doctors,800
Berlin,Plumbers,900
Paris,Doctors,900
Paris,Lawyers,800
Paris,Plumbers,500
Paris,Dog catchers,400
```

Sorting the CSV file based on by descending order of lawyer salary

The output should the like this:

```
Tokyo,800

London,700

Delhi,400
```

I am using the following code.,

```
import csv       
reader = csv.DictReader(open('salaries.csv','rb'))    
rows = sorted(reader)    
a={}    
for i in xrange(len(rows)):    
    if rows[i].values()[2]=='Lawyers':    
        a[rows[i].values()[1]]=rows[i].values()[0]    
t = [i for i in sorted(a, key=lambda key:a[key], reverse=True)]    
p=a.values()    
p.sort()    
p.reverse()    
for i in xrange(len(a)):    
    print t[i]+","+p[i]
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
NameError("global name 'a' is not defined",)
```

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: On which line do you get that error? If I run your code on the csv file provided, I get the expected output (python 2.7)

Comment: Why did you put a blankline between each code line?

Comment: @Wouter In the forth line:
NameError("global name 'a' is not defined",)

Comment: Thats not possible because on the 4th line, you *define* `a`

Comment: How are you calling this code ? Do you have it in file or running in interactive mode ?

Comment: Its an online compiler. 
But when I am running it in my machine, it gives correct output.
But I need to submit the code in an assignment online .  
@jbub

Comment: Ah i thought so, seems like a bug on their side, or maybe some kind of restriction, dunno.

Comment: @DipayanDev, what is the online repl?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham 

 I needed to add 
from __future__ import with_statement

Now its working. May be they are using some old version :)

Comment: @DipayanDev,  what version of python are they using?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Don't know . Might be older then 2.7.

Comment: @DipayanDev, the with statement was introduced in 2.5 so it must be a very old version of python.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it a lot simpler:

```
with open("salaries.csv") as f:
    dct = csv.DictReader(f)
    out = [(d["City"], d["Salary"])
          for d in dct if d["Job"] == "Lawyers"]

    out.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[1]),reverse=True)
    print(out)
[('Hong Kong', '1100'), ('Tokyo', '800'), ('Paris', '800'), ('London', '700'), ('Delhi', '400'), ('Lawyers', '400'), ('Moscow', '200')]
```

`(d["City"], d["Salary"]) for d in dct if d["Job"] == "Lawyers"]` finds all the rows with `Lawyers` then we extract the City and Salary from the dict.

Then  `out.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[1]),reverse=True)` sorts the list of tuples based on the integer value of the second element which is the `Salary`.

Comment: This is solving the OP's assignment, without solving his particular issue (NameError).

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

with open('salaries.csv','rb') as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    reader.next()
    sorted_salary=sorted(reader, key=lambda t: int( t[2] ), reverse=True)
    for row in sorted_salary:
        if row[1] == 'Lawyers':
            print '{0},{1}'.format(row[0], row[2])
```

Comment: SyntaxError('invalid syntax', ('', 3, 9, "with open('salaries.csv','rb') as fin:\n"))